# Cocoa: Check if two NSArrays are equal

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

I have two NSArrays of NSRects (stored using NSStringFromRect(NSRect)). Is there a quick way to check and see if the items in the array are equal or will I have to do a loop? So item 1 in array 1 = item 1 in array 2, etc. etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you check the [NSArray Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), you'll find a handy `-isEqualToArray:` method that should do just what you want

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation for `-[NSArray isEqualToArray:]`:

> Compares the receiving array to another array. Two arrays have equal contents if they each hold the same number of objects and objects at a given index in each array satisfy the `isEqual:` test.

This is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks to both. I checked the reference page (actually still had it up in another tab) and it was a case of looking right at it without seeing it...doh...